# Jquery ui autocomplete on multiple input fields with ajax results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to do what several other people have accomplished here on stack. I have tried all of the examples available and cannot seem to get this to work. I've copied working examples and reflected changes to match my case and still, nada.

HTML I am using looks like this.

```
<tr>
            <td><a id="remRow"><span class="icon icon-squared-cross"></span></a></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" data-type="itemID" name="itemID[]" id="itemID" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" data-type="item_name" name="item_name[]" id="item_name" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Item Name"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="item_sku[]" id="item_sku" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" placeholder="SKU#"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="item_qty[]" id="item_qty" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" placeholder="Qty"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="item_rate[]" id="item_rate" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" placeholder="Cost"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="balance[]" id="balance" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" placeholder="Balance"></td>
            </tr>
```

Jquery I've gotten from a working source to demo

```
//autocomplete script
$(".autocomplete_txt").keyup(function(){
    type = $(this).data('type');
    if(type =='itemID' )autoTypeNo=0;
    if(type =='item_name' )autoTypeNo=1;    
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'ajax.php',
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                   name_startsWith: request.term,
                   type: type
                },
                 success: function( data ) {
                     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        var code = item.split("|");
                        return {
                            label: code[autoTypeNo],
                            value: code[autoTypeNo],
                            data : item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,            
        minLength: 0,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
            id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id_arr.split("_");
            element_id = id[id.length-1];
            $('#itemID_'+element_id).val(names[0]);
            $('#item_name_'+element_id).val(names[1]);
            /*$('#quantity_'+element_id).val(1);
            $('#price_'+element_id).val(names[2]);
            $('#total_'+element_id).val( 1*names[2] );*/
            calculateTotal();
        }               
    });
});
```

lastly, the PHP to handle the json.

```
case "fetchAll": {

        $query = $db->rawQuery("SELECT itemID, item_name, item_sku FROM items ORDER BY item_name ASC");
        if($query) {
            $data = array();
            foreach($query as $key => $val) {
                //echo $val['itemID'];
                $name = $val['itemID'].'|'.$val['item_name'].'|'.$val['item_sku'];
                array_push($data, $name);
            }

            echo json_encode($out); 
        } else { echo "error"; }
    }
    break;
```

I constantly get the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined no matter what example I use. I've tried using the jquery 3.0, and downloaded the latest jquery.ui thinking that that may be the problem. I've also tried reverting back to older versions to check that.

I am convinced at this point that I am simply missing something. 3 days is a bit ridiculous so I am asking for help. I know there are similar questions on stack and yes, I have tried them all. If you've not all ready guessed I am not too good with jquery. I can get everything else to work even ajax calls, but, this...

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLHardman:

Try to use the following script inclusion in your head section:

**Html file:**

```
<head>

<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

    //autocomplete script
    $(".autocomplete_txt").keyup(function(){
        type = $(this).data('type');
        if(type =='productCode' )autoTypeNo=0;
        if(type =='productName' )autoTypeNo=1;  
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'ajax.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                       name_startsWith: request.term,
                       type: type
                    },
                     success: function( data ) {
                         response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            var code = item.split("|");
                            return {
                                label: code[autoTypeNo],
                                value: code[autoTypeNo],
                                data : item
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            autoFocus: true,            
            minLength: 0,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
                id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
                id = id_arr.split("_");
                element_id = id[id.length-1];
                $('#itemID_'+element_id).val(names[0]);
                $('#item_name_'+element_id).val(names[1]);
                /*$('#quantity_'+element_id).val(1);
                $('#price_'+element_id).val(names[2]);
                $('#total_'+element_id).val( 1*names[2] );*/
                calculateTotal();
            }               
        });
    });


  });




</script>
</head>
```

I couldn't replicate your scenario, but it seems you have conflicts with your jquery scripts. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you Joel, I am still having some issues with this as I cannot yet get the list to show up. I will play with this for a little while and see what I can come up with. At least I don't have that annoying error anymore so a good step in the right direction. I would have never caught that.

Comment: Try to encode your JSON response in a different structure. Using the pipes for separating the words probably is not a good approach. Keep on going...

Comment: I will play with the JSON response and see if i can get a regular parse. I have got this working now. I had made some changes while waiting for some help in the db query as well as how the data is passed to the PHP. These changes where failing. Your appreciated.