# How can I get my jquery autocomplete to fill in multiple fields in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, razor, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to setup an autocomplete in jquery that gets information from a user in Active Directory. A user can type in a few letters of a person's last name, and what returns is a 2D list (List>) that contains all the people whose last name starts with those letters. Each List holds the first, middle, last name and AD name of a person. And of course, each List> element represents a person.

I have no issues getting the data in jquery. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to make it populate the Employee_Name and Employee_Name_AD fields with the information in this array once the user clicks on a name from the list. This is my jquery code:

```
@section page {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var name;
            var adname;
            $("#TESTING").autocomplete(
                {
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Employees/GetUserList",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: { query: request.term },
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    name = item[0] + " " + item[1] + " " + item[2];
                                    adname = item[3];

                                    return { label: name, data: [name, adname] };

                                }))
                            },
                            select: function (event, ui) {

                                $('#Employee_Name').val(ui.data.item.data[0]);
                                $('#Employee_Name_AD').val(ui.data.item.data[1]);
                            }
                        })
                    },                    
                });
        })
    </script>
}
```

And on the same page, here is the accommodating Razor code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("TESTING")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee_Name_AD, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee_Name_AD, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee_Name_AD, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I found something super close to what I want thanks to stack overflow: http://jsbin.com/vasuliru/2/edit?html,js,output

The problem with the previous example is that the data is declared on the page itself, not pulled from a data source. How can I modify my code to get it to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally about to find a solution, after I came across something in php: [Jquery ui autocomplete on multiple input fields with ajax results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839894/jquery-ui-autocomplete-on-multiple-input-fields-with-ajax-results).

My final code is this:

```
@section page {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var name;
            var adname;
            $("#UserLookup").autocomplete(
                {
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Employees/GetUserList",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: { query: request.term },
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    name = item[0] + " " + item[1] + " " + item[2];
                                    adname = item[3];
                                    console.log(adname);

                                    return { label: name, data: item }

                                }));
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        console.log(ui.item);
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                        var userid = ui.item.value;
                        console.log("Here is the userid:");
                        console.log(item);
                        console.log(ui.item.data[3]);
                        $('#Employee_Name').val(ui.item.value);
                        $('#Employee_Name_AD').val(ui.item.data[3]);
                    }
                });                    

        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: great code...could you help me with the code of controller? thank you